# How to mark attendance timeout on browser close?

Tags: javascript, php

I am new in development and am developing an attendance system in core php....
Basically I want to know how to store the attendance timeout in database at the time when somebody closes the browser he should logout as well.

Comment: modern browsers have a sendBeacon function that could help - or use websockets

Comment: Before posting a question, you should have done the proper research and made attempts to solve your issue yourself. Then, if you get stuck on something _specific_, come back and show us your attempt. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `window.onBeforeUnload` event.

Also, as suggested in comments, `sendBeacon` experimental function also could be used.